# Using Rohloff with a thicker chain

Tags: chain, rohloff

I have a Bosch/Rohloff bike that currently uses a 3/32 chain. Seems like that's the standard for Rohloff hubs. Problem is, I'd much rather use a 3/16 chain, i.e. a chain that's exactly twice as thick. Are there Rohloff sprockets designed for this? And if not, how difficult is it to manufacture a 3/16-compatible Rohloff sprocket?

**Update:** even though I'm still sticking with 3/32 chains, I'm now using the stupidly thick (8.8mm pin length) Connect 7R8 chains.

Comment: Guessing - but its the internal width of the chain plates that matter.  A thicker chain won't make any difference provided the plates are the same distance apart.  And length will be the same - all normal bicycle chain is 1/2" pitch (ie between pins)

Comment: Why do you want to use such a wide chain? 1⁄8" is the wider standard for single speed and hub geared bikes. I thought anything wider was for use on freight bikes and heavy adult tricycles.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus mainly because of the very heavy loads on the chain. I annihilate a chain in about 2-3000km of travel and changing chains is getting really annoying. I'd rather buy a heavy chain and do it less often.

Comment: Rohloff  seems to use a proprietary thread for their sprockets. Manufacturing one is easy - *if* you have a CNC mill and the ability to precision harden steel☺. I would have thought that others would manufacture compatible sprockets.

Comment: seems pretty short to annihilate a chain if lubricated, unless you are riding in mud and sand. Perhaps a fully enclosed chain case is worth trying? Certainly the first thing I would get if I have a single speed chain setup. https://www.dutchbikebits.com/hesling-original-chaincase Had one on a motorbike once - it was beyond brilliant for chain life

Comment: @HenryCrun the single-speed setup I have goes over a tensioner

Comment: Either you need a better chain gauge or you need to clean and lube your chain more often.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus can you elaborate on this? I know people with CNCs and now that the sprockets aren't threaded anymore, what's to stop me from making one?

Answer (score 5):

This maybe late but KMC now manufacture a 1/2" X 1/8" splined sprocket for Rohloff hubs https://www.kmcchain.eu/webshop-sprocket

With a matching 1/8" chainring you can now use a 1/8" chain no problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the find!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a wider chain, even with narrower sprockets. As long as it's got a matching pitch (1/2") and it doesn't rub anywhere on the bike when fitted.